# Does a minor's siyum allow one to eat meat in the nine days?

Tags: minor-katan-child, nine-days, siyum

*Ashk'nazim* do not eat meat or drink wine during what's commonly called the nine days (the first nine or so days of *Av*). However, they may do so at a *mitzva* meal, such as one that celebrates the *siyum* (completion) of study of a tractate of Talmud. Can an adult eat meat and drink wine at a meal in the nine days that celebrates a **minor's** *siyum*? Does it count?

Answer (score 10):

Rabbi *B'tzal'el* Stern (*B'tzel Hachochma* [volume 4 number 100](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1809&st=&pgnum=411)) was asked whether a minor's *siyum* exempts an adult from *taanis b'choros*.

He cites the *Rambam* ([*Hilchos Korban Pesach* 5:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=9250)) as saying that someone who became an adult between *Pesach* and *Pesach sheni* need not offer the *korban pesach sheni*. The explanation of this *Rambam* is that, because the Torah says to include an entire household, including children, on the first *pesach* offering, it's as though the then-child fulfilled the *mitzva* just like an adult (even though normally we say children are exempt from *mitzvos*).<sup>1</sup>

Rabbi Stern extends this to Torah study: because a parent has a Torah obligation to teach his son Torah, it's as if the son has fulfilled a *mitzva* by studying Torah just like an adult. Therefore, Rabbi Stern concludes, his *siyum* can be used to exempt an adult from *taanis b'choros*.

(Rabbi Stern's *t'shuva* is cited as practical *halacha* [by Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899066110.html).)

It seems to me that the same logic applies to eating meat or drinking wine during the nine days. The Torah study is like an adult's, the *siyum* renders the meal a *mitzva* meal, and those participating in the *siyum* can eat meat and drink wine. But consult your rabbi for a practical ruling.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This follows Rabbi Stern's understanding of the *Kesef Mishneh* ([ad loc.](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=87037&rid=9250), citing [Rabbi *Yosef* Kurkus](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A1)) and *Mabit* ([*קרית ספר*, ad loc.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14000&st=&pgnum=358)), that the father's obligation to include his minor son in the *korban pesach* essentially allows an adult-level fulfillment of the obligation by the son.</sub>

<sub>An alternative understanding of the *Kesef Mishneh* is expounded by Rabbi *Chaim* Soloveitchik. He argues that there are two legal aspects to the fulfillment of the *korban pesach* commandment. The first is the individual's obligation to perform a commandment, and the second is the legal completion of the sacrificial service. Rabbi Soloveitchik contends that only the second aspect of the *korban pesach* applies to a minor, so the minor's parent is capable of including him in a household group for the *korban*'s consumption. Since the *korban pesach* service could be performed by a minor, its prior performance has legal significance for him once he reaches the age of majority. However, it is not as if he actually fulfilled an obligation as a minor.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Rav Eliyashiv (Ashrei Ha'ish 69:12) held that a katan who makes a siyum and makes a celebratory meal is not considered a seudas mitzvah which would permit one to have meat and wine.

Comment: If I remember correctly Rav Shmuel Kamentsky leaves this question off with a tzarich iyun