# May a man eat meat if attending the siyum of a woman?

Tags: food, women, torah-study, nine-days, siyum

The [Rema on the Shulchan Aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43895/7034) states that if one partakes of a seudat mitzvah such as a siyum then a person may eat meat or drink wine during the nine days. I would like to know if any poskim speak about whether or not a man who attends a [siyum made by a woman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60614/if-one-or-more-women-complete-a-talmudic-tractate-can-they-make-a-siyum) may similarly eat meat and drink wine.

I am unsure if the principle that a person who has a lesser obligation (in this case women learning torah) cannot exempt someone who has a greater obligation (man learning torah) would apply here.

Comment: Attending a Siyum isn't exempting your obligation in Torah learning

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61415/759

Answer (score 8):

Rabbi Shlomo Wahrman z"l in 1981 in his sefer [She'erit Yosef vol. 2:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51882&st&pgnum=56) answers in the affirmative, that a man may eat meat and drink wine at such a siyum.

Comment: R [Hershel Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) is cited [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/881565/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-eating-meat-in-the-nine-days-at-a-woman-s-siyum/) as agreeing with this responsum.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to say no, since women are exempt from Torah study, so it would not qualify as a seudat mitzva.

Comment: This isn't worth much since it's just your thoughts without any basis.

Comment: This seems to be based on the premise of *motzi acheirim*. I.e., only one who is, himself, obligated in a mitzvah can fulfill other people's obligations. A *siyum* would not come in this category as it is not obligatory.

Comment: Note the other answer that gives an actual teshuvah that it is permitted.

Comment: What about parts which they are equally obligated as men (such as Kitzur)?