# Honoring female Rabbis - sources

Tags: halacha, women, rabbis, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

*Sorry I'm stuck with this topic...*

I am looking for sources on various Halakhot of honoring female Rabbis (*knowledgeable women that tech Judaism*). My basic assumption is that as many rule that כיבוד רב is learned from קל וחומר from כיבוד אב ואם (see Mishna B"M 31a), there's no difference between male Rabbis and female Rabbis.

```
Clarification**: *I do not discuss the question 
of the ordination of female Rabbis, 
just like honoring male Rabbis does not require one.*
```

1. Does honoring Rabbis include honoring female Rabbis in general?
2. If yes, does it apply to men and women, i.e. should men honor female Rabbis?
3. Do school teachers that teach Tanakh and Halakhah qualify as Rabbis?
4. If for a son his Rabbi takes precedence over his father, is it true for a daughter with her female Rabbi?

Thank you.

Comment: If you replaced "she-Rabbi" in your question by "highly knowledgeable Jewish woman" would you get answers that would satisfy you? Otherwise you are mixing politics with your question and might get lots of comments/answers saying "we don't recognize She-Rabbis"

Comment: Good question! +1

Comment: @mbloch Sorry I'm not fluent in English. What's the difference between "female Rabbi" and "she Rabbi"?

Comment: @AlBerko there is none. Probably female rabbi is clearer. I was asking something else. Since we don't have Orthodox female rabbis, your question opens a can of worms. Do you really mean the few people who have been appointed as "female rabbis" by Open Orthodoxy? Or do you mean non-orthodox "female rabbis"? Or do you mean "knowledgeable women" without a focus on the title of rabbis?

Comment: @mbloch In Israel, female teachers (often married to rabbis) are called רבנית. I suspect the question was about them

Comment: @ba well, not just in Israel, in many places. If the OP speaks of *rabbaniot* then he should say so, or call them "rabbi's wives". Unless I'm the only one to be confused about she-rabbis which I understood to be female rabbis.

Comment: If you accept the suggestion of @mbloch this might be related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/is-a-female-torah-scholar-accorded-the-same-honors-as-a-male

Comment: I’d like to take a different approach to this question than mbloch, on the grounds that כיבוד רב in the context of the Mishnah in BM is very different than כיבוד רב in the context of the Gemara in Kiddushin. In Kiddushin, it’s talking about a knowledgeable Talmud Chacham. But if you specifically refer to returning the lost object of one’s Rebbe, a broad knowledge of Torah doesn’t matter - it’s what they’ve taught *you*. Take a look further in the Gemara in BM - all opinions agree to that, it’s just a matter of how much they need to teach.

Comment: @mbloch Thank you, I added a clarification. I refer to female Rabbis in general, just like the term male Rabbi s very general.

Comment: @ba I added a clarification, I mean women that teach (boys or gils or grownups) in general

Comment: @DonielF I agree.

Comment: @AlBerko Based on your edit, why isn’t this a duplicate of Kazi’s linked question?

Comment: @DonielF You're right it is close. put it on hold I will edit it to elaborate the question. All the answers talk very generally "they are equal...", "need to rise...". I'll think how to rephrase it.

Comment: @AlBerko Do you have enough rep to bounty that question to look for more specific answers?

Comment: @DonielF This question is more specific than the one it's marked as a duplicate of. Bounties are not meant for getting more specific answers than what the question itself asks. Since this post includes different questions than the other post, it shouldn't have been marked as a duplicate, in my opinion.

Comment: @ba I didn't read the questions carefully before closing, instead relying on this asker's indication that he agreed to closure  amd his indication he was planning to edit further. Since anyway answers in advance of such an edit would premature, addressing a draft version of the question, I closed the question to answers temporarily, pending the  edit.